# bool vs bit * 8

Tags: c++

Здравствуёте, у меня достаточно конкретный вопрос:
Стоит ли пренебрегать переменными bool типа опционной переменной из, например, 8 бит:

```
class SapperFieldCellAccesser
{
        // bool
    bool flagged;
    bool opend;
        // bit
    typedef char Options;
    Options options;
public:
    A() : flagged(false), opend(false), options(0) {} 

    bool BitIsFlagged() { return options & 1; }
    bool BitIsOpend() { return options & 2; }
        // vs
    bool BoolIsFlagged() { return flagged; }
    bool BoolIsOpend() { return opend; }
};
```

Comment: что значит пренебрегать?  Они тут вообше не нужны, и вообше такой класс ничего не делает

Comment: выше указанным кодом, я не собирался конкретизировать ситуацию, просто, есть ли смысл всегда использовать  options, или возможно, подстать ситуации варьировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, единая переменная с битовыми флагами позволяет легко и эффективно реализовать работу с несколькими флагами одновременно, в том числе с набором флагов, который формируется во время выполнения - через битовые маски. Для набора разрозненных полей типа `bool` естественным образом это реализовать не получится.

Во-вторых, набор полей типа `bool` займет больше памяти, чем "упакованная" переменная с битовыми флагами. Имеет ли это для вас значение - зависит от вашей задачи, т.е. от того, насколько массово инстанциируется данный класс.

В-третьих, не упомянут третий вариант: набор bit-fields размера 1 типа `bool`. Такой вариант обладает всеми преимуществами из "во-вторых", но в то же время всеми недостатками из "во-первых".

P.S. Если вы собрались работать с битовыми флагами, то тип для хранения таких флагов надо выбирать беззнаковый. Не `char`, а `unsigned char`. Или `uint8_t`. Или еще что-то в этом роде.

Comment: В четвертых работа с флаговой переменной медленнее, чем с `bool` или `LONGBOOL`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, не всегда.  В некоторых архитектурах есть команды условного перехода по значению указанного бита.